# Is it possible to access a string from a different interface

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to access this string from a different interface. Is that possible?

```
export interface WeatherComponent implements OnInit {
   name: string;
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. You could cast any object to this interface and access the member. Weather it exists is a different matter `var obj = { }; var asInterface = <WeatherComponent >obj; console.log(asInterface.name)`

Answer (score 0):

Sure - check out `Extending Interfaces` of the docs: [LINK](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

```
interface WeatherComponent {
   name: string;
}

interface NewWeatherComponent extends WeatherComponent {
    id: number;
}

let temp = <NewWeatherComponent>{};
temp.name= "foo";
temp.id= 10;
```

Edit: If you need a class that implements `WeatherComponent` to also implement `OnInit` then your `WeatherComponent` needs to extend `OnInit`. Tnx to *@jcalz* for the comment.

Comment: An interface declaration cannot have an 'implements' clause.
Either you and @JohnDoe meant to write `class WeatherComponent implements OnInit` or `interface WeatherComponent extends OnInit`.